# String isn't a type.dart(not_a_type)

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm relatively new to Dart and Flutter and I'm running in a basic error I'm not able to fix at the moment.

I get the following error in VS Code:

> String isn't a type.dart(not_a_type)

That's my code snippet:

```
    [String] getIntArrayFor({PurposeEnum purpose, String categoryName}){
      switch(purpose){
        case PurposeEnum.somePurpose:
          return [];
        default:
          return [];
      }
    }
```

The error is marked at both `String` keywords in the function header.

Does anybody have an idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want your method to return an array replace `[String]` with `List<String>`:

```
  List<String> getIntArrayFor({PurposeEnum purpose, String categoryName}){
  switch(purpose){
    case PurposeEnum.somePurpose:
      return <String>[] ;
    default:
      return <String>[] ;
  }
}
```

You can find more information about dart lists (which are the equivalent of arrays in other languages) in this official flutter docs [link](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-core/List-class.html).